# Magento 2: Issue with Upload two modules on marketplace

Tags: magento2

I have two modules in my extension
eg: Abc
      xyz1
      xyz2

I need to upload it on the marketplace. Do I need to create the meta-package or have to do another thing?

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things into that one.

1. Upload one extension as `add-ons` on Marketplace first. For example (Abc xyz1)
2. Now you need to upload another extension as main extension on Marketplace (Abc xyz2)

**NOTE** 
Remember, you already specify dependency of **main** extension into add-ons.

Comment: Can you please provide me the example? Am struggling with this

Comment: You can visit our extension : https://marketplace.magento.com/magecomp-module-codverification.html
where diffrent API like BulkSMS, MSG91, Twilio we can upload as add-ons and main package as extension.

Comment: Link is not working.

Comment: Now its working